# In how many ways can $3$ natural numbers $a, b, c$ be chosen from $1$ to $100$ (inclusive) such that $a < b < c$?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can $3$ natural numbers $a, b, c$ be chosen from $1$ to $100$ (inclusive) such that $a < b < c$?

Comment: "such that a ... "  Is something missing?

Comment: Can you complete your question?

Comment: Yes im sorry. For some reason when i type < it dosent appear. Any way i fixed it

Comment: When you pose a question here, you should include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: @ItzikWeizman Your question can be rephrased as: In how many ways can we select 3 different numbers between 1 and 100 such that the order does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

Here $a,b,c$ are selected from $\{1,2,3,\cdots,100\}$ and $a<b<c$

Which can be done by $$\binom{100}{3}$$